# Heroku serving public assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm not trying to host a static site, I just have an XML file that I use with Nokogiri to build a database. However, in production on Heroku it doesn't seem to be serving the public files directory in the format public/filename.xml - I'm not sure why but I'm guessing its something to do with how Heroku compiles the asset pipeline.

I've seen some resources on tailoring Heroku to serve up static websites, but nothing on enabling static public files.

Any ideas?

Comment: Got any error responses etc?